# Invoke a method of a web service from a Java (Android) external app

Tags: java, android, web-services

sorry if the question is too easy, but I do not know the answer..
What I have to do is to invoke a method of a web service using a java app.
Here you can find a web service:
http://muovi.roma.it/ws/xml/autenticazione/1
And I want Invoke the method called "autenticazione.Accedi:"

I have a python example that is doing this:

```
from xmlrpclib import Server
from pprint import pprint

DEV_KEY = 'Inserisci qui la tua chiave'

s1 = Server('http://muovi.roma.it/ws/xml/autenticazione/1')
s2 = Server('http://muovi.roma.it/ws/xml/paline/7')

token = s1.autenticazione.Accedi(DEV_KEY, '')

res = s2.paline.Previsioni(token, '70101', 'it')
pprint(res)
```

But I need the same operation in Java... Can anyone help me in this problem?

thank you

Comment: what kind of a method is it ( GET,POST..) ?

Comment: actually, I do not know

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you using this project as a Library.

https://github.com/matessoftwaresolutions/AndroidHttpRestService

It makes you easy deal with apis, control network problems etc.

You can find a sample of use there.

You only have to:

- Build your URL
- Tell the component to execute in POST/GET etc. mode
- Build your JSON

I hope it helps!!!

Comment: I've developed this component. Everybody who has use it find it easy, because of the explanation (README) an the sample. If you need more help, I could answer you as soon as possible. Ask me whatever you need.

Comment: I didn't tried it yet, but with this library is it possible call methods of a web service?

Comment: Yes. You have to make them public in their path (make an API), and you can call them without any problem. Like an ordinary httpRequest. ;)

Comment: yes but I have no access to the website... it is an open data....
Anyway, I think I found something useful here: http://tldp.org/HOWTO/XML-RPC-HOWTO/xmlrpc-howto-java.html
In this way I will able to invoke a web service's method from my third-part-app directly, just writing something like this: server.METHOD_NAME
but I didn't tried yet, so I'm not sure if it works :)

Answer (score -1):

```
package com.example.jojo.gridview;
import android.util.Log;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
/**
* Created by jojo on 12/10/15.
*/
public class WebService {
    String url="http://192.168.1.15/Travel_Dairy/";


    String invokeGetWebservice(String webUrl)
    {
        String result = "";
        webUrl=webUrl.replace(" ","%20");
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(webUrl);
        HttpResponse response;
        try {
            response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            if (entity != null) {
                InputStream inputstream= entity.getContent();
                BufferedReader bufferedreader = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(inputstream), 2 * 1024);
                StringBuilder stringbuilder = new StringBuilder();
                String currentline = null;
                try {
                    while ((currentline = bufferedreader.readLine()) != null) {
                        stringbuilder.append(currentline + "\n");
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                result = stringbuilder.toString();
                Log.e("Result", result);
                inputstream.close();
                return result;
            }
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e1) {

            Log.e("ClientProtocolException", e1.toString());
            return result;

        } catch (IOException e1) {

            Log.e("IOException", e1.toString());
            return result;

        }
        return result;
    }
    public List<DataModel> getTrips() {
        String getname="view_details.php?";
        String completeurlforget=url+getname;
        //String seturl= "ur_id="+userid;
        //String finalurl=completeurlforget+seturl;
        String result=invokeGetWebservice(completeurlforget);
        try {
            JSONArray jsonarry=new JSONArray(result);
            List<DataModel> ar=new ArrayList();
            for(int i=0;i<jsonarry.length();i++)
            {
                JSONObject jsonobj=jsonarry.getJSONObject(i);
                DataModel user=new DataModel();
                user.setName(jsonobj.getString("name"));
                user.setImage(jsonobj.getString("image"));
                ar.add(user);
            }
            return ar;
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: You have provided a code block but did not give any other feedback.  Consider adding some explanation along with the code to make this a better answer.